# Android exported database corrupted

Tags: android, database, sqlite, webserver, corrupt

We have an Android and we are sending the database for a Backup to a Web Server to do a backup on the server.

The problem is that the file that the server receives is without extension, and corrupted !

```
bouton_export.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            //ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getBaseContext());
                            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            File file = new File("data/data/fr.univtours.appelsuaps/databases/Appel.db");

                                            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

                                            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.quentinlozach.com/get_database.php");

                                            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                                            reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);
                                    httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);
                                    HttpResponse response = null;
                                            try {
                                                    response = client.execute(httpPost);
                                            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                            }

                                    if((response.getStatusLine().toString()).equals("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")){
                                        // Successfully Uploaded
                                        Log.i("uploaded", response.getStatusLine().toString());
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        // Did not upload. Add your logic here. Maybe you want to retry.
                                        Log.i(" not uploaded", response.getStatusLine().toString());
                                    }
                                    }
                            }).start();

                    }
```

Any idea where it comes from ?

Thanks.

Comment: The extension is the responsibility of `get_database.php`. Is the database open while this is executed?

Comment: No, the database is closed actually :/